# oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: Cannot instantiate class

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm getting the following error while trying to access a page in adf application on the dev server:
 <org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag>  <Error when processing tag for component with id: "pgl1". The scoped id of the parent component is ":psl1".
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: Cannot instantiate class 'org.test.view.bean.TestBean'.

But I'm able to access the page in the application without any errors in my Local 12C WLS and other server. Please help!

Comment: Which exact JDev version do you use? Which WLS version is running on the server? Is the right ADF runtime installed on the server?

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Timo Hahn! WLS version running on the server is 12.2.1.3.0 and I will check and update you regarding the installation of ADF runtime on the server.

Comment: Hi Timo, sorry for the very late response, we have reinstalled WLS and ADF runtime is installed correctly, still we are facing the same issue. Kindly let me know if there is any way we can do to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: and the JDev version I use is 12.2.1.3.0

Comment: What wls version do you use? Does it match your JDev version? Did you define the org.test.view.bean.TestBean in the taskflow?

Comment: yes Timo, the wls version matches the JDev version and the TestBean is defined in the taskflow. The application is deployed on two servers, it works fine on one of the servers and we're getting this error on the other server.

Comment: rename the bean e.g. to MyBean (so no Test in it) and show the code referring  to the bean so that we see the socpe.